# Is there a way to post from Azure Event grid to Azure DevOps incoming webhook

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-eventgrid

I would like to use the new Azure Update Manager and to have some kind of update orchestration. I want to be able to trigger an Azure DevOps pipeline via an incoming webhook. So I created the webhook in Azure DevOps, placed it as a resource in the pipeline and tested it successfully via postman

```
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: mywebhook
      connection: mywebhook
```

But when I want  to create a Pre Maintenance event and call my Incoming Webhook In Azure DevOps, Event Grid would send a request to the Azure DevOps with the following body:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2d1781af-3a4c-4d7c-bd0c-e34b19da4e66",
    "topic": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "subject": "",
    "data": {
      "validationCode": "512d38b6-c7b8-40c8-89fe-f46f9e9622b6",
      "validationUrl": "https://rp-eastus2.eventgrid.azure.net:553/eventsubscriptions/myeventsub/validate?id=0000000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000000&t=2022-10-28T04:23:35.1981776Z&apiVersion=2018-05-01-preview&token=1A1A1A1A"
    },
    "eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
    "eventTime": "2022-10-28T04:23:35.1981776Z",
    "metadataVersion": "1",
    "dataVersion": "1"
  }
]
```

However this body is not accepted by Azure DevOps because the payload is an **array** and not a single object thus my pipeline is not triggered and also I cannot see the validation URL to validate my Event Grid subscription. I tried to use a custom event schema but due to the fact that I use Maintenance Configuration topic type, custom event schema is not possible.

So is there a way to communicate between Azure Update manager and Azure DevOps using a webhook to facilitate Update orchestration?
[Azure Update Manager/Event Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmYYu.png)

1. Created webhook in Azure Devops.
2. Successfully called the webhook and triggered the pipeline using Postman
   POST https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/mywebhook?api-version=6.0-preview
3. When I try to access the webhook from Azure Update Manager/Event grid - the webhook is not triggered due to the payload mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue from my side. The pipeline can be triggered by the webhook successfully when I post from Postman. However, if I add `https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview` as the endpoint when create an event grid, it will fail with error message `Webhook validation handshake failed for ... Http POST request retuned 2XX response with response body . When a validation request is accepted without validation code in the response body, Http GET is expected on the validation url included in the validation event(within 10 minutes)`. It seems that DevOps doesn't send response to event grid, so that the validation will fail.

As a workaround, you can create a [logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-webhooks#logic-apps) or [function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-functions). Set your app URL as webhook endpoint when creating the event. Then trigger the DevOps pipeline via your app.

Comment: It seems like Event Grid always outputs an array of events, even when there is a single event batch. The Azure DevOps incoming webhook simply cannot handle arrays of objects and the pipeline is not triggered. 

That's very unfortunate. One would think that 2 Micosoft services would be able to communicate to each other. Unfortunately the Incoming webhook functionality in AzureDevOps is too basic and even proper logging of unsuccessful triggers is missing.